# Dependência circular em API Rest com Spring Boot

Tags: java, api, rest, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Estou me aventurando no desenvolvimento de uma API Rest usando Spring Boot, JPA com Hibernate e Maven para gerenciar os repositórios.
Na minha modelagem eu tenho uma classe `Club`:

```js
@Entity
@Table( name = "CLUB")
public class Club {

   /**
    * Id da entidade
    */
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

    /**
    * Atual técnico do clube.
    */
   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "actualClub")
   private Coach coach;
   
   //Outros atributos, getters e setters
  }
```

que tem um relacionamento `@OneToOne` com a classe `Coach`:

```js
@Entity
@Table(name = "COACH")
public class Coach extends Person {

   /**
    * Clube atual do técnico.
    */
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "CLUB_ID")
   private Club actualClub;

   //Outros atributos, getters e setters
   
}
```

A Classe `Person` tem alguns atributos adicionais, entre eles o `id`, que segue a mesma lógica implementada em `Club`.

Por fim, tenho também a classe `ClubController` para lidar com algumas requisições:

```js
@RestController
public class ClubController {

   /**
    * Instância da classe de serviços da entidade <i>Club</i>
    */
   @Autowired
   private ClubService clubService;

   /**
    * Retorna JSON que representa o clube com o 'id' especificado.
    *
    * @param id Identificador do clube a ser buscado.
    * @return ResponseEntity Objeto com detalhes da requisição HTTP, como o Status.
    */
   @RequestMapping(value = "/clubs/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
           method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<?> getClubById(@PathVariable Long id) {

      final Club club = this.clubService.findById(id);
      if (club != null) {
         return new ResponseEntity<>(club, HttpStatus.FOUND);
      } else {
         return new ResponseEntity<>("Não encontrado", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
      }
   }
   
   /*Entre outros métodos...*/
   
}
```

O problema que estou tendo é que o JSON retornado possui uma relação circular entre `Club` e `Coach`. Ou seja, eu recebo os dados do clube, entre eles os dados do técnico. Dentro dos atributos do técnico há novamente os dados do clube e assim continua... *x(*

E isso certamente vai acontecer também quando eu for relacionar `Club`com `Player` mais adiante.

Uma solução que encontrei foi esta: [Link](https://dzone.com/articles/circular-dependencies-jackson). Que usa `@JsonIdentityInfo` na declaração das classes. Um problema que percebi nessa solução é o overhead de informações que nem sempre são necessárias. Por exemplo, quando for `@OneToMany` com `Player`, eu traria necessariamente todas as informações dos jogadores ao buscar por um clube.

Pesquisando mais um pouco, eu encontrei uma outra posível solução (ainda não testei) do próprio Sring: [Spring HATEOAS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/). Dessa forma eu conseguiria adicionar links (href) para certos atributos, e só faria a requisição para obter mais informações se realmente fosse necessário. Mas vi também que o HATEOAS ainda possui algumas limitações.

Então minha dúvida é: qual seria a melhor abordagem para esses casos? Tem alguma outra opção?

Minha ideia mais pra frente é consumir essa API em um aplicativo iOS. (Isso pode ser importante para ajudar na resposta)

Comment: Detalhe 1: se a opção com `@JsonIdentityInfo` for a escolhida, eu teria que usar UUID para os campos @Id do JPA, conforme o Link detalha.

Detalhe 2: A API do Spotify usa uma abordagem parecida com o HATEOAS [link](https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/3f9zqUnrnIq0LANhmnaF0V), ao buscar uma **track**, há um campo `href` para o **artist**.

Answer (score 1):

Eu trato essa referência da seguinte maneira.

No lado da associação que eu quero que seja gerado o json eu anoto o atributo com 
`@JsonManagedReference`, e do outro lado eu anoto com `@JsonBackReference`.

Se na serialização do objeto for encontrado o `@JsonBackReference`, neste objeto esse atributo não será serializado pois o outro lado carregar essa responsabilidade,